# Looking for a better to write this copy loop that will increase speed

Tags: excel, vba

This code is taking information from one sheet 1 and populating it to sheet 2.  My issue is that as sheet 1 increases in length, the time to populate sheet 2 is too much. Is there a better way for me to write this that will decrease the time it takes?

```
 For i = 1 To (Worksheets("records").Range("C11").Value)

   If (Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 3).Value > 0) Then
   
       xrange = "B" & (i + 22) & ":R" & (i + 22)
       
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 3).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 3).Value   'eventnum
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 4).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 4).Value   'status
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 6).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 7).Value  'date
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 8).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 9).Value 'unit
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 10).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 10).Value 'system
      
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 16).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 15).Value 'failure
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 18).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 16).Value 'credit

      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 12).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 18).Value 'demand
      Worksheets("Master").Cells(i + 22, 14).Value = Worksheets("records").Cells(i + 10, 19).Value 'response

      Else
        
   End If
        
Next i
```

Comment: How long does it take to run? It looks like that loop should be fast. Maybe turn off screen updating and calculations if you have formulas.

Comment: As the code works, perhaps the Code Review stack?

Comment: Moderate but `For Each` range loops are moderately more efficient. You are also grabbing some cells that are right next to each other so you could transfer both of those values in one line. Also, are you doing anything with `Else`? If not, you can remove that. Also unclear if you are doing anything with `xrange`

Comment: Why do not you just filter the rows and they copy the range to the other cell?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using a number of constants in your code – possibly without realising it.  The source of your values always *starts* on Row 11, the destination always *starts* on Row 23 – and the columns for both source and destination are fixed.  As such, you don’t need to loop at all, but rather get your values in one lump of data for each column – once you’ve established the last row in each case.

The following code achieves this, and will massively reduced the amount of traffic between VBA and the worksheets – and will never increase as your data increases.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Val2Val()
Dim wDest As Worksheet, wSrce As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
On Error GoTo GetOut

Set wDest = Worksheets("Master")
Set wSrce = Worksheets("records")

i = wSrce.Range("C11").Value + 22
j = wSrce.Range("C11").Value + 10

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 3), wDest.Cells(i, 3)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 3), wSrce.Cells(j, 3)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 4), wDest.Cells(i, 4)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 4), wSrce.Cells(j, 4)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 6), wDest.Cells(i, 6)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 7), wSrce.Cells(j, 7)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 8), wDest.Cells(i, 8)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 9), wSrce.Cells(j, 9)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 10), wDest.Cells(i, 10)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 10), wSrce.Cells(j, 10)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 16), wDest.Cells(i, 16)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 15), wSrce.Cells(j, 15)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 18), wDest.Cells(i, 18)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 16), wSrce.Cells(j, 16)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 12), wDest.Cells(i, 12)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 18), wSrce.Cells(j, 18)).Value
wDest.Range(wDest.Cells(23, 14), wDest.Cells(i, 14)).Value = wSrce.Range(wSrce.Cells(11, 19), wSrce.Cells(j, 19)).Value

Continue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Exit Sub
GetOut:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Continue
End Sub
```